# How to prevent HTML encoding for embedded expressions in XML Literals (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

With the following code:

```
Dim x As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = _
<div>
<%= message.ToString() %>
</div>
Dim m = x.ToString()
```

...if message is HTML, then the < and > characters get converted to `&lt;` and `&rt;`.

How can I force it to skip this encoding?

Comment: Wow, it's been a whole year, but it's not too late to accept an answer for this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the type of your `message` variable?  If `message` is an `XElement`, then just leave off the `.ToString` call like this:

```
Dim x As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = _
    <div>
        <%= message %>
    </div>
Dim m = x.ToString()
```

If `message` is some other type (like `StringBuilder`), then do this:

```
Dim x As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = _
    <div>
        <%= XElement.Parse(message.ToString()) %>
    </div>
Dim m = x.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the HTML snippit as an XML document and append the document node to the Div node you are creating.

If you want to add XML (or HTML) to an existing XML document then you have to add it as XML and not as text (cause that gets encoded).